# Creación de una Biblioteca de clases en un proyecto WCF

Tags: c#, wcf

Mi pregunta es que en un proyecto WCF puedo crear una biblioteca de clases como arquitectura de capas "Data" y poder referenciar al proyecto WCF.

Pregunto esto debido a que el proyecto es grande y no quisiera combinar los métodos de la base datos dentro del archivo svc que brinda WCF para tener un mejor orden y entendimiento.

Espero su respuestas y Gracias

Comment: Podras tener una libreria de clases, y consumirla desde WCF o cualquier proyecto compatible .

Comment: En teoria, si agregas una biblioteca de clases, esta no te va a quedar en el proyecto del WCF, te va a quedar en otro dentro de la misma solucion (y recuerda que una solicon es basicamente un contenedor de proyectos). Por tanto no habria lio.

Comment: Muchas Gracias Amigos.